# Can't start program without using sudo

Tags: sudo, monodevelop

I have monodevelop 5.7 installed on my computer with ubuntu 14.10, but when I tried run it from launcher and from the command

```
~$ monodevelop
```

they didn't work.

But when I used the command

```
~$ sudo monodevelop
```

it worked ok, monodevelop started.

How can I run monodevelop from launcher and command line without using sudo?

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: What happens if you don't use sudo? What error message do you get?

Comment: Nothing happened. When I typed monodevelop without sudo, a while later the terminal return normal state (I mean ~$).

Comment: locate the executable using whereis and use chmod to change its permissions.

Comment: You could try making a .desktop file that will run the program as sudo.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Quote from above: "How can I run monodevelop from launcher and command line **without using sudo?**" - By the way, you should **not** run GUI applications with `sudo` on Ubuntu, but with `gksudo` or `gksu`. And it is recommended to use any variant of `sudo` as rarely as possible and only when it is unavoidable.

Comment: @ByteCommander OK. I'll remember the `gksudo` thing, but the .desktop file is something that can be run from the launcher and command line.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Of course, but MonoDevelop is a GUI program, so it should rather be used with a graphical sudo variant to prevent permission mess on user files. But I don't see a reason why an IDE should need to be run as root at all! So no sudo is better than any sudo, wherever you can avoid it.

Comment: If I try to edit .desktop file in line Exec as Exec=gksu monodevelop, I can run program from launcher (password is required), but from terminal still don't work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all look for permission-related errors with: `strace monodevelop`.

If you found it, change the permissions to that files/directories to match your user. It also helps if you delete every monodevelop-related directories from userspace.